# Didgeridoo sounds different to me compared to others

Tags: didgeridoo

I'm learning to play the didgeridoo, believe I have some basic rhythms and can circular breath (needs more practice, easier to hide with a rhythm). However, I realize the sound I hear in my skull is not what others hear.

For example, when I make a small cavity I'm my mouth along with the drone, I hear and feel a very strong higher overtone in that cavity. It's fun to move that around and develop it in different parts of the mouth, and they each have their own qualities.

However, I don't think this sound is as strong to others as it is to me. When I place my phone (crappy mic I'm sure) at the end of the horn it doesn't record what I hear ... It's much more boring.

What's going on?

Comment: This could be the same reason that your voice sounds different when recorded the. When you hear it while speaking. Your skull may very well be vibrating contributing to the timbre.